# Eclipse doesn't start because of Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, eclipse, version

I need to keep switching my OS java version and eclipse java version sometimes (which I do via `sudo update-alternatives --config java`
 and preferences -> chossing appropriate installed jre, respectively).

This time, after switching from java 8 to java 7, eclipse refuses to start. When I double click the icon and choose my workspace, it says :

> An error has occurred. See the log file
>   /home/user/eclipseWorkspace/.metadata/.log.

The log file essentially says this ( I have pasted more details from the log file at the end) :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jetbrains/java/decompiler/main/decompiler/ConsoleDecompiler : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

This question isn't a duplicate of similar major.minor version issues. I am not even able to launch eclipse with my old workspace, which I need to as there are too many working sets consolidating about a 150 sub projects. So at the very least I need to be able to extract those working sets. How can I either fix this error or export working sets ?

Full log file :

```
    !SESSION 2018-12-20 08:32:00.980 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.5.0.I20150603-2000
java.version=1.7.0_80
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_AU
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 4 2 2018-12-20 08:32:11.240
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt".
!STACK 0
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jetbrains/java/decompiler/main/decompiler/ConsoleDecompiler : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.sf.feeling.decompiler.fernflower.FernFlowerSourceMapper.<init>(FernFlowerSourceMapper.java:25)
    at org.sf.feeling.decompiler.editor.SourceMapperFactory.getSourceMapper(SourceMapperFactory.java:26)
    at org.sf.feeling.decompiler.editor.JavaDecompilerClassFileEditor.doOpenBuffer(JavaDecompilerClassFileEditor.java:171)
    at org.sf.feeling.decompiler.editor.JavaDecompilerClassFileEditor.doOpenBuffer(JavaDecompilerClassFileEditor.java:147)
    at org.sf.feeling.decompiler.editor.JavaDecompilerClassFileEditor.doOpenBuffer(JavaDecompilerClassFileEditor.java:139)
    at org.sf.feeling.decompiler.editor.JavaDecompilerClassFileEditor.doSetInput(JavaDecompilerClassFileEditor.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3220)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2098)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3238)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3265)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:319)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:898)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1306)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.postProcess(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.event 4 0 2018-12-20 08:32:11.294
!MESSAGE Exception while dispatching event org.osgi.service.event.Event [topic=org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/ui/UIElement/widget/SET] {ChangedElement=org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.PartImpl@4a0c806e (elementId: org.eclipse.e4.ui.compatibility.editor, tags: [Editor, org.sf.feeling.decompiler.ClassFileEditor, removeOnHide], contributorURI: null) (widget: null, renderer: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer@31c8341b, toBeRendered: true, onTop: false, visible: true, containerData: null, accessibilityPhrase: null) (contributionURI: bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor, object: null, context: PartImpl (org.eclipse.e4.ui.compatibility.editor) Context, variables: [], label: null, iconURI: platform:/plugin/org.sf.feeling.decompiler/icons/decompiler.png, tooltip: null, dirty: false, closeable: true, description: null), EventType=SET, AttName=widget, OldValue=ContributedPartRenderer$2 {}, Widget=null} to handler org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler@3fce2e6b
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$TextEditorSavable.<init>(AbstractTextEditor.java:7172)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.getSaveables(AbstractTextEditor.java:7136)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveablesList.getSaveables(SaveablesList.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveablesList.preCloseParts(SaveablesList.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveablesList.preCloseParts(SaveablesList.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveablesList.preCloseParts(SaveablesList.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.firePartClosed(WorkbenchPage.java:4971)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart$1.handleEvent(CompatibilityPart.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4633)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.UIElementImpl.setWidget(UIElementImpl.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.unbindWidget(SWTPartRenderer.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer$1.widgetDisposed(SWTPartRenderer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1327)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1351)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1136)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3806)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1139)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3806)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1139)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3806)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1139)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3806)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1139)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3806)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1139)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3806)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1139)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3806)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1139)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3806)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1139)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3806)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:1368)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.releaseChildren(Canvas.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.releaseChildren(Decorations.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.releaseChildren(Shell.java:2646)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1139)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:3806)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.dispose(Shell.java:2577)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)


!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-12-20 08:32:11.930
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.JFaceResources.getResources(JFaceResources.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.JFaceResources.getResources(JFaceResources.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.WorkbenchPart.dispose(WorkbenchPart.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.PageBookView.dispose(PageBookView.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.AbstractDebugView.dispose(AbstractDebugView.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.views.variables.VariablesView.dispose(VariablesView.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.invalidate(CompatibilityPart.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.destroy(CompatibilityPart.java:394)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:898)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:159)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2018-12-20 08:32:13.072
!MESSAGE The workspace will exit with unsaved changes in this session.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be running Eclipse Mars (4.5) with Jetbrains decompiler code. Eclipse Mars will run with Java 7 but the Jetbrains code requires Java 8 or later.

Comment: I had to launch eclipse using a new empty workspace,  uninstall the eclipse class decompiler 3.1.1 and relaunched eclipse with my old workspace and it worked. Thanks for pointing this out. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> This time, after switching from java 8 to java 7, eclipse refuses to start.

Modern Eclipse requires it be run using Java 8.